# Como determinar o último elemento de uma lista em um foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, lista

Dado uma lista qualquer, como saber se o `foreach` está no último elemento?

Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso, a que mais vejo é salvar o último elemento e verificar se o elemento atual é igual, mas dessa forma é necessário fazer a verificação em cada *loop*, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var last = list.Last();

foreach(var element in list)
{
    if(element == last)
    {
       //is last
    }
}
```

Essa é a melhor forma em questão de performance?

Comment: Tem casos que o `Last()` vai acabar iterando por toda a coleção. Será que é uma boa ideia usar um `for`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tem alguns casos em que usar o método `Last` pode acabar causando uma iteração em toda a coleção, por exemplo, quando a coleção é resultado de uma consulta Linq. Isso iria fazer com que a coleção fosse iterada **duas vezes**. O que, com certeza, você vai querer evitar - principalmente se for trabalhar com coleções grandes.

Como você já deve saber, o `foreach` em si não tem nada que possa te ajudar nisso. A solução é achar alguma solução alternativa.

#### 1. Usar um for

Essa é a primeira que eu cogitaria usar

```
for(int i; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if(i == list.Count - 1)
    {
    }
}
```

#### 2. Usando uma variável contadora dentro do *loop*

Também há a opção de "cachear" o tamanho da lista e usar uma variável contadora (não vejo vantagens nessa abordagem comparada ao uso de `for`)

```
var index = 0;
var count = list.Count; //ou Count() - você sabe
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(++index == count)
    {
    }
}
```

#### 3. Usando o método [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (var item in list)   
{   
     if (list.IndexOf(item) == list.Count - 1) 
     {
     }
}
```

Particularmente, eu te desencorajaria a usar esta abordagem porque o método `IndexOf` procura um elemento na coleção **através de um *loop***, ou seja, a cada iteração do *loop* principal, outra iteração será feita no método `IndexOf`.

Você pode confirmar isto vendo o código fonte do método [`IndexOf` de `List<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,612) e o do método [`IndexOf` da classe `Array`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1315)

Comment: Sim, é uma opção, mas queria saber se o `foreach()` possuía algo mais eficiente. Ahhh, tem como fazer o `Count - 1` com o `foreach()` também. xD

Comment: Pois é, eu percebi isso depois também. Acabei de editar a resposta =D

Answer (score 4):

Eu não iria por este caminho.

Como disse o LINQ este é um caso onde o `for` pode ser uma ideia melhor, assim é só comparar o índice com o `Count()` ou `Length` da lista (possivelmente cacheado).

É possível usar a mesma técnica dentro de um `foreach`, mas teria que ter a variável índice para comparar com o total de itens (menos 1 para indicar o número do último). Se é para ter esta variável, porque não fazer um `for`? Algo asim:

```
var count = list.Length;

foreach(var element in list) {
    if (--count > 0) {
        //is last
    }
}
```

Em alguns casos é possível usar alguma opção com `foreach`. Poderia armazenar o valor do último item e comparar com o atual. Mas tem que garantir a unicidade dos valores na lista toda. Arriscado.

O `foreach` é adequado quando se quer iterar sobre a lista de forma mais uniforme, em casos assim ele não é tão adequado. Mas depende de cada caso.

Se puder usar outra forma (não faz tanto sentido), [achei uma solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17460853/221800) destrinchando o que o `foreach` faz:

```
using (var enumerator = .GetEnumerator()) {
    var last = !enumerator.MoveNext();
    T current;
    while (!last) {
        current = enumerator.Current;
        last = !enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (last) {
            //is last
        }       
    }
}
```

Não gosto muito desta solução, e ela não pode ser usada em, todos casos, mas pode usar [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_ForEach_System_Action__0__):

```
elements.ForEach((element, info) => {
    if (info.IsLast) {
        //is last
    }
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/LastElement.cs).

Dá para ter outras soluções criativas, variações destas, mas no fim muda pouco, tem que fazer o que for mais adequado para o caso. Não se pode prender a uma forma, use o que for melhor no caso concreto.