# Como obter índice da iteração atual de um foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, índices

Normalmente, a fim de obter o índice da iteração atual dentro de um [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx), faço da seguinte maneira:

```
int i=0;
foreach (var elemento in list)
{    
   // Qualquer coisa
   i++;
}
```

Acredito que existam outros métodos para obter o índice da iteração <s>(até mais *"bonitos"* que o apresentado)</s>, quais são?

Comment: utilizar o for normal não é uma opção?

Comment: @NicolasBontempo minha dúvida se limita ao `foreach` mesmo.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como determinar o último elemento de uma lista em um foreach?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138009/18246)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade se precisa realmente do índice, o certo é usar o `for`.

Se não quer usar a ferramenta correta para o problema, a solução mais óbvia é a apresentada na pergunta.

Fora isso a solução que o pessoal costuma fazer é usar LINQ, o que eu acho um exagero para o problema e muito raramente é uma solução melhor que as anteriores em qualquer análise que se faça - se fizer uma análise geral, duvido que ela seja boa em qualquer situação. Seria algo assim:

```
foreach (var pair in list.Select((x, i) => new {Index = i, Value = x})) {
    WriteLine($"{pair.Index}: {pair.Value}");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VoIQqS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQ8RlT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/ForEachIndex.cs).

Acho menos legível, menos performático e não consigo ver qualquer ganho.

Alguns preferem criar alguma abstração em cima disso, como um método de extensão que esconda um pouco os detalhes de implementação, ou uma classe que trate disto. Em raros casos acho isso adequado. Dependendo do caso (onde um método substitui o laço) muda a semântica e poucos programadores sabem lidar com isso direito. Acaba sendo um exagero para evitar o uso óbvio e simples.

O que poderia deixar um pouco melhor, algo assim:

```
foreach (var pair in list.IndexPair()) {
    WriteLine($"{pair.Index}: {pair.Value}");
}

public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<T> IndexPair(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
        return enumerable.Select((x, i) => new {Index = i, Value = x});
    }
}
```

Já vi algumas soluções tão esdrúxulas que me recuso postar aqui.

Comment: @ramaral espero que não :) Eu vi algumas pessoas postando algo assim, mas acho que só a título de curiosidade. Tem linguagem que não tem mais o `for`, e pior não tem um `foreachindexable` que aí até faria sentido para uns casos, mas não para todos, acho um erro. Acho bom evitar o `for` quando dá, mas não a qualquer custo.

Comment: Quando eu aprendi linq, fiquei animado pra usar em tudo. Hoje em dia, sabendo das possíveis perdas em uma implementação falha(vamos ser sinceros e concordar que 90% dos que usam Linq não sabem o que ele faz de verdade), prefiro usar em casos em que o `foreach` não consegue fazer direito ( joins / predicated wheres, etc).
Bom pra saber, ... não muito bom pra implementar em produção. Opinião minha.

Comment: @EricWu virei seu fã :D

Answer (score 5):

O `foreach` é uma forma de loop mais elegante, para iterar sobre elementos de uma collection em várias linguagens. Na linguagem C# é usada para iterar sobre coleções que implementam o `IEnumerable`. Então ele vai chamando o método `GetEnumerator` o que retorna um `Enumerator`. Nesse `Enumerator` temos as propriedades:

```
MoveNext() atualiza o Current com o próximo objeto
```

e

```
Current retorna o Enumerator atual
```

Então, o conceito de índice no foreach não é encontrado. Ao invés de utilizar uma variável fora do foreach para controle do índice, é mais razoável em minha opinião utilizar o for normalmente:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
   list[i];
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

O `foreach` não possui conhecimento do índice atual para expô-lo de uma maneira elegante, você tem que controlar uma variável manualmente mesmo. Isso acontece porque o `foreach` é uma estrutura independente de um tipo de dado que precise trabalhar com indexamento por números. Ele trabalha somente sobre a interface `IEnumerable` e `IEnumerator`.

O fato de não possuir um índice no `foreach` faz todo o sentido, visto que você pode implementar usar o `foreach` em estruturas que não possuem indexamento, como uma `LinkedList`

Answer (score 1):

Não sei é a maneira mais eficaz e performática, porém seguindo a analogia para realizar a interação em cima de uma lista em python, podemos obter o índice em um foreach em c# e interar utilizando este índice em cima da lista da seguinte forma.

Exemplo:

```
 var lista = new List<int>(){ {100}, {200}, {300}, {400}, {500}, {600}, {700},  
                              {800}, {900}, {1000} 
 };     
foreach(var index in Enumerable.Range(0, lista.Count()).ToList())
    Console.WriteLine("Index item: "+ index + " valor item na lista: " + 
                       lista[index]);       
}
```

Desta forma ao invés realizar a interação através do foreach em cima da lista diretamente, cria-se uma nova lista de índices através do (Enumerable.Range) de 0 até o tamanho total da lista, assim criando uma lista de índices de 0 até o tamanho da lista em um intervalo de 1 em 1.

Sendo assim ao invés de interar diretamente em cima da lista desejada, faz-se a interação em cima da lista de índice onde cada índice ira corresponder a posição do elemento desejado na lista, assim sendo possível obter o acessar e  obter o índice do elemento da lista de forma similar a um for tradicional.

Segue exemplo no .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDyfdg

Answer (score 0):

Você usar o for para ter o controle da iteração, e usar ElementAt para pegar o valor

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                var lista = new List<teste>() {
                    new teste("João", 12),
                    new teste("Maria", 12),
                    new teste("José", 12),
                    new teste("Carlos", 12),
                    new teste("Juliana", 12),
                };


                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lista.ElementAt(i).nome);
                }


                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public class teste
            {
                public teste()
                { }
                public teste(string _nome, int _idade)
                {
                    this.nome = _nome;
                    this.idade = _idade;
                }
                public string nome;
                public int idade;
            }
```